# Can MS SQL Server 2000 handle Chinese text encoded with Unicode?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000, character-encoding

Now, I am using Ms sql server 2000 and I want to store my data as the unicode for chinese font. But I don't know it can store this type or not? If not, could anybody guide me?

Thanks,
Sopolin

Comment: You might want to put your question in the title.  eg 'Unicode fonts in MSSQL 2000'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The n in the nchar and nvarchar data types in Sql Server including 2k stands for Unicode. Yes you can.

Here's a few articles to look at for getting started: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa902669(SQL.80,lightweight).aspx#sql_dataencoding_topic2), [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/reporting-services/UnicodeInSQLServer.aspx)